# Initialize private field in mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a private field in my class and a method which is modifying it if a certain flag is set AND if a map contains certain value. I want to test that method and to see the result. Here's the code (irrelevant fields and methods ommited for brevity):

**My class:**

```
class UsersLoader {
   private Collection<User> users;
   private Map<Integer,Boolean> status;

   UsersLoader() {
      users = new ArrayList<>();
      status = new HashMap<>();
   }

   protected loadExternalUsers(boolean condition) {
      Collection<User> externalUsers = LoadUsersFromSomeExternalSource();
      if (condition && status.get(SOME_KEY)) {
         users.addAll(externalUsers);
      } else {
         /* do not modify my users */
      }
   }
}
```

**My test:**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class UsersLoaderTest {
   private UsersLoader loader;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      loader = mock(UsersLoader.class);
      doCallRealMethod().when(loader).loadExternalUsers(anyBoolean());
   }

   @Test
   public void testLoadingWhenFlagIsTrue {
      Collection<User> users = loader.loadExternalUsers(true);
      assertThat(users.size() == 1);
   }

   @Test
   public void testLoadingWhenFlagIsFalse {
      Collection<User> users = loader.loadExternalUsers(false);
      assertThat(users.size() == 0);
   }

}
```

When I run a test, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in `UsersLoader` class, in the line with IF clause which checks the `status.get(SOME_KEY)`. Even if I solve that, the next NPE would be one line below, because my `users` would be null. How can I initialize private fields in my mocked class so I can work with them? I can create a getter and a setter and mock them as well, but then the whole test loses its point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you could use a **Spy** instead of a mock.

This would trigger the constructor and assign an empty list to the private variable thus escaping the NPE:

```
private UsersLoader loader;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  loader = spy(new UsersLoader());
}
```

Now you do not need make this call:

```
  doCallRealMethod().when(loader).loadExternalUsers(anyBoolean());
```

Just keep in mind that you need to mock any methods that do not need to be triggered as implemented.

Comment: That is the correct answer. Mocking an object for testing it is ... well, plain wrong!

Answer (score 1):

First, move the initialization to the declaration of the field:

```
private Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you can inject this field with your own mock:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class UsersLoaderTest {
       @Mock
       private Collection<User> users;
       @InjectMocks
       private UsersLoader loader;
}
```

and then verify that the `users.add()` was called with the users you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mock UsersLoader.class, this is the class containing methods that you are going to test. When you create a mock, mocked class will not be implement instead you can mock the functionalities of the class. Rather spy it or just instantiate and provide check hand written check for the functionality. In the later case you do not need Mockito at all. So you can spy it and use the feature of mockito to test the functionality